# How to change Linux shell in a remote computer that does not support ypchsh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tcsh

How do I change shell in a remote PC? I am logged into a cluster with a Bash and the output I see is

```
elan@l01:~ $ chsh
chsh: can only change local entries; use ypchsh instead.
elan@l01:~ $ ypchsh
-bash: ypchsh: command not found
```

Since I have no root privilege there, I can not install ypchsh in the cluster. Is there any other way to change shell without invoking ypchsh?

Note 1:
Browsing, it looks like another user who installed the same software (currently not available for questioning) has .cshrc in his directory, with the right settings. His .bashrc is minimal and has no redirections.

The /etc/passwd has no entry for either of us.

```
getent passwd
```

shows entry for both of us, but shows only /bin/bash for both.

Note 2:
The sofware has been developed with autotools, and using bash instead of tcsh is known to have created wrong builds. (I am not changing shell because I fancy it.)

Thank you,
Elan

Answer (score 7):

In your `.bashrc`, put `exec tcsh` last.

Comment: +1 for using `exec`, but that belongs in `.bash_profile` instead, since that file is the first looked for by an interactive login shell (http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files).

Comment: Thank you, I am new to Linux. I had assumed only chsh can change shell, but as you indicated, just calling the shell's name (tcsh in my case) on commandline changes it (checked: export is not recognized any more, but setenv is). But (1) the echo $SHELL command shows still bash. More importantly, I need to edit the .cshrc for some environment variables. But (2) no .cshrc has been generated. These two points confuse me. Is this still a minor workaround effecting not the same as chsh?

Comment: Is the solution here to
1. create a .cshrc myself and put my stuff in 
2. change shell every time by calling tcsh on the command line of bash
3. use 'source .cshrc' every time
4. build the software
?
I just noticed that I have to exit twice or thrice when I invoke a shell within another, which gave me the above idea.

Comment: In my case, I wanted to switch from `sh` to `bash`. I had to create `~/.profile` and add `exec /bin/bash` to switch from `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score -2):

Once you're in bash in the cluster, why don't you just type `tcsh`?  And if that works, why not just add it as the last line of `.bashrc`?